# Why is my write() method in Odoo not setting the value?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-12

I have inherited some model. I need also to override it's write method.

I've tried this:

```
@api.multi
 def write(self, vals, context=None):
     res = super(WebSiteSupportTicket, self).write(vals)
     date = datetime.datetime.now()
     if vals['state_id']:
         if vals['state_id'] == 7 or vals['state_id'] == 8:
             vals['closing_date'] = date
     print(vals)
     return res
```

Where *closing_date* is a Datetime field.

When I make the change of *state_id* to the state with id 7 or 8, *closing_date* is still being null. But I know the code is passing through the if statement because I can see *closing_date* on the print of *vals*

First time I run into a problem with write method. Why is happening and how can I get a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added the `closing_date` to the values dict after you called `super`, the `closing_date` will not be written.

Remove the `context` argument from the function definition (not needed). You can find an example where they override the invoice [write](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L1969) method in account module.

***Example***:

```
@api.multi
def write(self, values):
    # Define the closing_date in values before calling super
     if 'state_id' in values and values['state_id'] in (7, 8) :
         values['closing_date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    return super(WebSiteSupportTicket, self).write(values)
```